# jquery json post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cakephp

Well, im trying to post a variable in jquery to my controller. But it seems that the posting is not successful. I am not getting any value when i try to retrieve it in my controller. It says undefined index. Here's what I have:

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buttons').click(function(){
        var data = $(this).attr("value");
//      var test = 'test';

        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'maps','action'=>'instantiateButtonValue'));?>',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
//          success:function(data){
//              alert(data);
//          },
//          error:function(data){
//              alert(data);
//          }
        });
    }); 
});
```

my controller:

```
function instantiateButtonValue(){ 
            echo $_POST['data'];


//          $this->set('data','some');
//          $this->render('json');

        }
```

Comment: did you check with firebug, what exactly it is sending. Also I think you should enclose with " quotes instead of ' quotes in URL.

Comment: ive done what you have said but enclosing it with " quotes doesn't work... and regarding with checking of what it is sending to my controller, nothing is being sent so data is null.. i really wonder what is wrong..

Comment: Have you tried printing the entire POST array, to see if it is even sending the value?

Comment: oh wait hold on.. when i checked what it is posting, there appeared the value im trying to post.but i think i am not able to retrieve in my controller

Comment: yep..its always undefined index

Comment: Use firebug to debug the ajax call. see if it's returning an error or something

Comment: So, to make sure we're on the same page here.. You tried print_r($_POST).. I have to make sure because, it shouldn't return 'undefined index', if you're printing the entire array, and not specifying one.  Even a completely empty array will still print a result without that error message(I just tested this on my local machine).

Comment: And that is..?  What is the key/value pair?

Comment: i found a solution however mine is just temporary.. imean, i believe my solution is just for a single variable being passed to the controller..

Comment: [data] => myvalue Daedalus...

Comment: my answer is quite for retrieving singular item..what if it is in the format of an array like what you have presented to me? would it be the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enclose with " quotes instead of ' quotes in URL.

From PHP you should encode as JSON instead of direct echo, to retrieve the value by JQuery.
like below

```
echo json_encode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: i found a solution however mine is just temporary.. imean, i believe my solution is just for a single variable being passed to the controller..

Answer (score 0):

i got an idea from this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864515/post-ajax-and-php-json-submission?rq=1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buttons').click(function(){
        var data = $(this).attr("value");
//      var test = 'test';

        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'maps','action'=>'instantiateButtonValue'));?>",
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {data:data},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }); 
});
```